# Facebook change thumbnail, tittle, secription when using SEF and non SEF URL of the same page

Tags: joomla-3.3.x, url, sef, facebook, non-sef-url

When I post on facebook debugger an URL article it fetches different datas if use SEF or non SEF URL

The SEF URL displays the information correctly (thumbnail, title...) but the non SEF URL desperately retrieves the data from the home page.

Since I do need to sometime change the menu items title, I can't use the SEF URL otherwhise they would be broken. (The facebook links of my post can't depend on my menu name).

How could I force facebook to fetch the correct thumbnail, tittle, description of the article even if I use the non SEF URL?

Adding some meta tags directly on my index.ph (such as "og:title" etc.) in the head section would not work since it would force facebook to alsways retrieve the same thumbnail, titles etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non SEF Urls can be troublesome. Query parameters are usually associated with tracking and usually discarded by Facebook.

You can test how Facebook scrappes your site with the Debugger tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

In JED, you can find several extension to add Facebook Open Graph Tags.

Comment: thanks for your reply! Yes, but is there a way to force fb to fetch the right data?

Comment: Sure, you can Facebook Open Graph Tags  to guide the scrapper.

Comment: ok, but the question remains: how? Since I probably need to write these  Facebook Open Graph Tags in index.php how could I write them according to Joomla query parameters?

Comment: No, you do not modify index.php. In JED, you can find several extension to add Facebook Open Graph Tags.

Comment: Thank you Anibal, I found the plugin easy open graph which does the job.